# Sort directory-files

Tags: sorting, emacs

I have the following directories:

- mod01
- mod02
- mod03
- ...
- mod100

When I use

```
(list (directory-files dir t "\\(mod\\)\\([0-9]\\)" nil))
```

the output is:

- mod01
- mod02
- mod03
- ...
- mod10
- **mod100**
- ...
- mod99

As you can see, **mod100** is not in the correct position.The desired output is:

- mod01
- mod02
- ...
- mod10
- mod11
- ...
- **mod100**

Thank you for your advice

Comment: It's much easier to rename all your `modN` and `modNN` to `mod00N` and `mod0NN` respectively, and then apply traditional sorting.

Comment: Yes, it is an easy solution, but I would like to preserve the structure of the modules `modNN`. Most of my projects have less than 100 modules, this is an exception.Thanks

Comment: If one of the answers solved the problem, please accept it.

Comment: The answer from Jürgen Hötzel is correct. How can I accept it?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer - there should be a grey checkmark next to the answer: click on it and it will turn green to indicate that you accepted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supply a custom predicate function extracting the numeric part:

```lisp
(sort
 (directory-files dir t "\\(mod\\)\\([0-9]\\)" nil)
 (lambda (x y)
   (<
    (string-to-number (replace-regexp-in-string ".*mod\\([[:digit:]]+\\).*" "\\1" x))
    (string-to-number (replace-regexp-in-string ".*mod\\([[:digit:]]+\\).*" "\\1" y)))))
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. I found a solution but yours are very elegant.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the help doc for `directory-files` sorting uses the predicate `string-lessp`, for which `(string-lessp "100" "9")` returns `t`. You could write your own predicate and set `nosort` to true and use `cl-sort` to sort the contents by extracting the numeric part of the strings. If you are on a machine with access to `sort -V`, you could just wrap a shell command,

```
(defun my-sort (&optional dir)
  (interactive "D")
  (with-temp-buffer
    (shell-command
     (concat "ls " (shell-quote-argument (or dir default-directory)) "| sort -V")
     (current-buffer))
    (split-string (buffer-string) "\n")))
```

Using `sort`'s version sorting should result in the desired ordering.

Comment: Yes, I would like to use the option using my own predicate. In fact I am searching for a solution like this: `(sort dirs #'(lambda (x y) (string-lessp x y)))` could you give me some directions on how to extract the numeric part of the strings in the body of the `lambda`?. Thanks

Comment: Hi, I found the solution. I will answer the question myself, code review is welcome! Thanks